# How to load custom model in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I'm trying to load my pretrained model (yolov5n) and test it with the following code in PyTorch:

```
import os  
import torch 
model = torch.load(os.getcwd()+'/weights/last.pt')
 

# Images
imgs = ['https://example.com/img.jpg']   
# Inference
results = model(imgs)

# Results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()

results.xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (pandas)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 3 import torch
> 4
> ----> 5 model = torch.load(os.getcwd()+'/weights/last.pt')

My model is located in the folder `/weights/last.py`, I'm not sure what I'm doing false. Could you please tell me, what it's missing in my code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to find the weights in this directory: yolov5/runs/train/exp/weights/last.pt

Then you load the weights with a line like this:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp/weights/last.pt', force_reload=True)
```

I have an example of a notebook that loads custom models and from that directory after training the model here https://github.com/pylabel-project/samples/blob/main/pylabeler.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

In order to load your model's weights, you should first import your model script. I guess it is located in `/weights/last.py`. Afterwards, you can load your model's weights.

Example code might be as below:

```
import os  
import torch 
from weights.last import Model # I assume you named your model as Model, change it accordingly

model = Model()  # Then in here instantiate your model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(ospath.join(os.getcwd()+'/weights/last.pt')))  # Then load your model's weights.

 

# Images
imgs = ['https://example.com/img.jpg']   
# Inference
results = model(imgs)

# Results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()

results.xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (pandas)
```

In this solution, do not forget that you should run your program from your current working directory, if you run it from the weights folder you might receive errors.

Comment: Thanks! I used yolov5 for training. Where can I find my model? I cant see in weights folder any other data.

Comment: I do not know Yolov5 but if you got the source code from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5,  I think it is located as models/yolov5.py

Comment: thanks @hus. But I really still couldn't get it worked. I can't see py file in model folder. Do you have any idea where or how I can find it? I saw the folder https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/tree/master/models here but it also didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanna load your local saved model you can try this

```
import torch

model = torch.hub.load('.', 'custom', 'yourmodel.pt', source='local')
```